# Manger du chou-fleur est / c'est

Tags: grammaire

Pouvez-vous me dire quelle variante est la meilleure ?

1. De mon point de vue, manger du chou-fleur **est** plus sain que de manger du chou vert.
2. De mon point de vue, manger du chou-fleur, **c'est** plus sain que de manger du chou vert.

Comment: On ne parle pas couramment "chou habituel" en France, tu veux parler du chou vert (on dit aussi chou frisé ou chou de Milan) ou du chou blanc ?  Pour la phrase envisager aussi : « c'est plus sain de manger du chou-fleur que de....  »

Comment: Je parlais du chou vert. En français, un infinitif peut être le sujet de la phrase ?

Comment: Oui, un infinitif peut être sujet de la phrase :  « Manger du chou est bon pour la santé ». Chou est masculin donc on dirait du chou habitu**el** (mais si tu demandes ça dans un magasin tu ne seras pas compris !).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les variantes « ***A est B*** » et « ***A, c'est B*** » sont toutes deux correctes et idiomatiques.

Aucune n'est « meilleure » que l'autre. La deuxième met l'emphase sur le sujet, est d'un registre plus courant et se rencontre plus souvent à l'oral qu'à l'écrit.

Comment: Apparemment, on trouve de plus en plus la deuxième construction et des variantes, telles que _demain, papa et moi nous allons faire les courses_ (avec ou sans virgule après _moi_), qui contient quand même une redondance au niveau du sujet. Même si _demain, papa et moi allons faire les courses_ est possible et ne contient pas "deux sujets", ça "gratte" un peu l'oreille (alors que j'aurais dit que c'était la seule tournure strictement correcte il y a 50 ans).

Comment: @Frank Plus personne ne dit ça, c'était déjà très soutenu il y a cinquante ans. À l'oral, la forme habituelle est : *Demain, papa et moi, on va faire des courses*.

Comment: Oui, je suis bien d'accord.